# How do I elegantly install RVM on Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I would like to install RVM onto my Ubuntu 13.04 running its distribution packaged Ruby 1.9.3p194.

What should I do to install a good RVM version to use this version of Ruby?
The [official website's installation directions are not clear](https://rvm.io/rvm/install).

I might upgrade my Ruby later but for now I figured I'll start with the version included in Ubuntu 13.04, as RVM would allow me to safely use newer versions anyway.

In Python, all you need to do is issue a one-liner and you have virtualenv fully installed.

Comment: You shouldn't use rvm and the repository's ruby together. I've run into plenty of problems with paths being wrong and there really aren't any benefits.

Comment: Is Ruby 2.0 recommended in terms of playing nicely with common IDE's and overall?

Comment: What have you tried? As it, it sounds like you haven't done anything. Try following the directions on [RVM's installation page](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) AFTER reading it. Ruby 2.0.0p247 is the current version and 2.0 has been out long enough for any decent tools to be updated. *I* don't recommend using IDEs, but some people like them.

Comment: Thanks for the input about 2.0. I think any installation page that starts off with a vague term is not a particularly good one. I'm referring to "Unless doing guided install". It then carries on with a reference to read an entire manual: "you should read all sub-sections under the RVM Section" and then the hyperlinks are in fact a circular reference which makes it really fit for the days people were still guessing their ways around man pages :)

Comment: Hi Matt - I wrote a blog post called "Ruby Version Manager (RVM) Overview for Rails Newbs" at the below link recently. I hope you find it useful. http://strandcode.com/2013/07/11/ruby-version-manager-rvm-overview-for-rails-newbs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the [Ruby downloads page](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) and scroll to the rvm section. Seems to provide the most straightforward explanation, and will also take care of getting the latest Ruby stable version that matches. Works well on Ubuntu 13.04 desktop for now. The official site is just (at the time of writing) too cluttered to make sense of.

Re-use at your own risk as time passes and things possibly change.

Answer (score 2):

Install the current version of RVM. The author and maintainers do a great job of keeping it up to date and react to bug reports quickly.

RVM's whole reason for existence is to manage multiple Rubies in your own home directory's sandbox, not to make it easier to manage a system-wide, default version of Ruby; It won't make that easier at all. RVM does allow you to access/use the system Ruby if necessary, but you have to revert to using the traditional `sudo` commands to modify things and if you don't know about permissions and when and why you should tweak it, you're better off leaving things alone.

Yes, RVM has a lot of functionality in it, but for most people only a few commands are needed. In general you'll start with `rvm use some_version_of_ruby --default` to set your initial/default version, then switch to other versions later using the same command without `--default`. Additionally `rvm install some_verson_of_ruby` will be how you tell RVM to install something new.

Installing RVM is trivial, and is a single-line command. You need to read the documentation though, to figure out what it is. All too often we see people who haven't paid attention to what they're doing and skip the directions and flail about. It *isn't* hard to figure out, especially if you're at all familiar with a Linux or Mac OS system.